# XY points not displaying

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, plotting

Using ArcMap, I am trying to add a series of co-ordinates to a map to show the distribution of shelf seas I am analysing. However, when I go through the process of adding XY data to the basemap, it will only plot 0, 0 (which isn't even one of my data points) but none of the actual 40 points.

The data is on an xls file, the lat and long is as decimals, with no spaces, and with - for south and west data.
I have tried projecting in a number of different coordinate systems (WGS 84, etc) but none produce any different result.

Also, despite there being data in the file, the attribute table is always empty (which is probably the issue, but I can't work out how to fill it).

Comment: Check the column name in your excel file, if they have space, accented character, special character, start with a number.... you get an empty table in arc. For your coordinate check that the decimal separator in excel is the one that ArcGis expect (otherwise the value is interpreted as text and not as coordinate)

Answer (score 1):

Your file is in ".xls" which is Microsoft's proprietary binary table format: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/cd03cb5f-ca02-4934-a391-bb674cb8aa06

Suffice it to say that these files don't play nicely with ArcGIS, but you can easily save the file in .CSV format in excel, then follow the steps you described to "Add XY Data". Just make sure you specify that your data are separated by commas when given the option. You can also follow the tutorial Esri provides here: https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/get-started-with-map-viewer/arcgis-online/lessons/add-a-layer-from-a-csv-file.htm